# ExpressJS 4.2 and flash error (TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'flash')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

im using ExpressJS 4.2 and PassportJS to authenticate local users.
Everything is fine except when I try to rise failureFlash message.
This is my conf, thanks in advance!

==== requires in app.js

```
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var favicon      = require('static-favicon');
var logger       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var passport     = require('passport')
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var flash        = require('connect-flash');
```

==== config in app.js

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

==== /admin route (routes/admin.js)

```
router.post('/admin', passport.authenticate('loginAdmin',{ successRedirect: '/panel',
                                                failureRedirect: '/admin',
                                                failureFlash: true }));
```

==== passport file (config/passport.js)

```
passport.use('loginAdmin', new LocalStrategy(

  function(username, password, done) {



    modeloUsuario.findOne({ nombre: username, password: password }, function(err, user)  {



      if (err) { return done(err); }

      if (!user) {

        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }


      return done(null, user, {message: "invalid login"}); //<- error problem
    });
  }
));
```

==== Finally, my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "connect-flash": "latest",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "ejs": "~0.8.5",
    "passport": "latest",
    "passport-local": "latest",
    "mongoose": "latest"
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Github/express-auth/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:111
          req.flash(type, msg);
              ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'flash'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initiliazed `flash` in your middleware in *app.js*.

Adding `app.use(flash)` before passport middleware should fix the problem.

See [connect-flash #usage](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash#usage) for more info.

Comment: Hi Waldo and thanks, I did that and now I'm getting:

Github/express-auth/node_modules/connect-flash/lib/flash.js:60
  if (this.session === undefined) throw Error('req.flash() requires sessions')
                                        ^
Error: req.flash() requires sessions

Comment: HI @mdv, I think the error message you're getting is pretty straightforward. 

"Connect-flash" requires [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to work. Again, as it is very clearly indicated on [connect-flash #usage](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash#usage), you have to install express session and require it : `var session = require('express-session');` and then initialize your different middleware in the *right* order, as it is precised on connect-flash's page.

Comment: So , 
`app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());`

That should work.